# Which solution is best, create connections, or call methods directly in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, class, qt5

Developing a pdf reader app. QT 5.11.0

[GitHub](https://github.com/andr1312e/PdfAndObjReader-QT)

I have a class PdfPresenter that contains the UI business logic for the View.

```
class PdfPresenter
{
public:
    PdfPresenter(PdfViewer* parentPdfViewer);
    ~PdfPresenter();

SOME CODE HERE
public:
    void OnClick(const QPoint event);//some logic

private://fields
    LinkHandler *m_linkHandler;
```

Earlier, the presenter talked with View using an interface. Recently I delete this thing because I think it creates an unnecessary abstraction layer.

Also, I have a LinkHandler class, that gets a link, defines its type, and does some things.

```
class LinkHandler
{
public:
    LinkHandler();

    void execute(Link link);

}
```

After detecting type I would like to call the parent method like go to the page, 2 methods I have.

My question:

Is it best practice to make all these classes depend on QObject and create signals and slots, or I should create a parent filed in LinkHandler and call methods directly?

Comment: It really depends. Signals and slots are very powerful, but runs slower.

Comment: You're asking for opinions, which is considered off-topic here. To get on-topic again, you could ask for the implications of taking either approach, but make sure you show an own effort.

Comment: I know, because of that I asked

Comment: I have only 2 methods to call, should I inherit from QObject for it

Comment: Or I should put this logic into the presenter class and don't worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good rule of thumb:

- If you know the exactly one place you want to notify, use a direct call.
- If you don't know how many, or which, places you want to notify, emit a signal.